# What should I do instead of using Onclick? And how to fix positioning

Tags: html, onclick, position

I have 2 questions

1:
I am very new to coding so I showed my code to others and was told I should not be using onclick but have no idea how to rewrite as something else.

2:
When I first launch the code or refresh it the Borderlands button when clicked shows the subbutton Borderlands#2 which when it first appears it is lower then I'd like it to be but once you click it again and it appears for the 2nd time its position is where I want it to be

https://codepen.io/MutantCreator/pen/xxQEeBJ?editors=1000
`

```
<head>
    <title> Games </title>
</head>


<style>
    .GamesButton {
        position: fixed;

        background-color: #494D49;
        padding: 14px 10px;

        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px;

        color: greenyellow;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;

        margin: 5px -3px;

        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: url('GamingIcon.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 27px;
        background-position: -3px 0px;
    }
    .GamesButton:hover {
        background-color: darkseagreen;
        transition-duration: .2s;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #494D49;
        padding: 14px 10px;

        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 20px;

        color: greenyellow;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;

        margin: 4px 30px;

        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .subbutton {

        background-color: #494D49;
        padding: 14px 10px;

        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 20px;

        color: greenyellow;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;                        

        margin: 4px 30px;  
        margin-left: 50px;                 

        cursor: pointer;
    }
    body {
    background-image: url('CarbonBackground.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    #BorderlandsDV2{

        width: 80%;
        right: 20px;
        padding: 5% 0%;
        background-color: #494D49;
        margin: 1px 30px;

        text-align: center;
        color: greenyellow;

        border: 2px solid #31CC22;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    #RimWorldDV{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 5% 0%;
        background-color: #494D49;
        margin-top: .1%;
        margin: 1px 30px;

        text-align: center;
        color: greenyellow;

        border: 2px solid #31CC22;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
     #TarkovDV{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 5% 0%;
        background-color: #494D49;
        margin-top: .1%;
        margin: 1px 30px;

        text-align: center;
        color: greenyellow;

        border: 2px solid #31CC22;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    #TerrariaDV{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 5% 0%;
        background-color: #494D49;
        margin-top: .1%;
        margin: 1px 30px;

        text-align: center;
        color: greenyellow;

        border: 2px solid #31CC22;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    #LeftSideBar{
      position: fixed; 
      left:0px; 
      top:-4px; 
      background-color: #494D49;
      border: 2px solid #000;
      width: 20px;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 100%;
    }
</style>




<script>
    function ShowAndHideBorderlandssubclasses() {
    var x = document.getElementById("subbuttonebl");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }
    }

    function ShowAndHideBorderlands2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("BorderlandsDV2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }
    }

    function ShowAndHideRimWorld() {
    var x = document.getElementById("RimWorldDV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }
    }

    function ShowAndHideTarkov() {
    var x = document.getElementById("TarkovDV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }
    }

    function ShowAndHideTerraria() {
    var x = document.getElementById("TerrariaDV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }
    }

    function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
    }
</script>





<body style="background-color:black;">

    <div id="LeftSideBar"></div>

    <button onclick="OpenGames()" class="GamesButton"></button>
    
   <li>
    <button onclick="ShowAndHideBorderlandssubclasses()" class="button Borderlands">Borderlands</button>
   </li>
         
    <li>
    <button ID=subbuttonebl style="display:none" onclick="ShowAndHideBorderlands2()"; class="subbutton Borderlands2";>Borderlands #2</button>
   </li>
        <div style="display:none" id="BorderlandsDV2">
            Description for BorderLands
        </div>

   <li> 
    <button onclick="ShowAndHideRimWorld()" class="button RimWorld">RimWorld</button>
   </li>
        <div style="display:none" id="RimWorldDV">
            Description for Rimworld
        </div>

   <li> 
    <button onclick="ShowAndHideTarkov()" class="button Tarkov">Tarkov</button>
   </li>
        <div style="display:none" id="TarkovDV">
            Description for Tarkov
        </div>

   <li> 
    <button onclick="ShowAndHideTerraria()" class="button Terraria">Terraria</button>
   </li> 
        <div style="display:none" id="TerrariaDV">
            Description for Terraria
        </div>
    

</body>
```

`

Comment: To replace your onclicks, look into event listeners. Here is an example of usage: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 1):

I get one part of your question as you want to replace onclick. Instead using onclick you can add event listener to your button for example

```
const btn = document.getElementById('your-btn-id')
btn.addEventListener('click',someFunction)
```

Event Listeners implies your button will listen until some event happens for more you can visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Adding `ul` seems to answered this question

But If you are new you should first learn more javascript first as for your second question I didn't get what you want to ask would you mind clearing a bit.

Comment: Thank you. And for the 2nd question (https://imgur.com/a/Ea75Qli) So The first image shows what it looks like when I first click the  "borderlands" button The space between the "borderlands" and "borderlands#2" is what I am trying to fix

Comment: Thank you for your explanation i get your question But when i ran it on my browser i didn't get your bug could you share what browser you are using. and try to add `ul` before your li tag as i found something here https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/what-happens-if-i-directly-add-the-li-without-adding-the-ul/380816

Comment: Yea I am using Firefox and ill try that right now

Comment: That seemed to work when I put ul so thanks